# Pass the 'this' object Meteor method in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, meteor, jasmine

I am trying to test a MeteorJS method with Jasmine and Velocity. The method uses the `this` object. I don't know how to call the method with that object The method is as follows:

```
Meteor.methods({
  deleteUser: function(userId) {
    if (this.userId === userId) {
      return Meteor.users.remove({
        _id: this.userId
      });
    }
  }
  ...
})
```

My test is given below:

```
it("test remove() user IDs match", function() {
    spyOn(Meteor.users, 'remove').and.callThrough();
    Meteor.call('deleteAccount', 1);
    expect(Meteor.users.remove()).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Unfortunately, the test is failing as I don't know how to pass the value of `this.userId` to the method (1 in `Meteor.call('deleteAccount', 1)` is `userId`). Can anyone tell me how to pass `this` to Meteor methods through a Jasmine test, please?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can set the `this` context manually in Jasmine:

```
it("test remove() user IDs match", function() {
    spyOn(Meteor.users, 'remove').and.callThrough();
    var thisContext = {userId: 1};
    var result = Meteor.methodMap.deleteAccount.call(thisContext, 1);
    expect(Meteor.users.remove()).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

If methodMap doesn't exist for you, you might need to follow some directions for [MeteorStubs](https://github.com/meteor-velocity/meteor-stubs).